# Kotlin arrow-kt, functional way to map a collection of either to an either of a collection

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I've been using kotlin arrow quite a bit recently, and I've ran into a specific use case that has me stuck.

Let's say I have a collection of some object that I want to convert to another datatype using a convert function. Let's also say that this convert function has an ability to fail-- but instead of throwing an exception, it will just return an Either, where `Either.Left()` is a failure and `Either.Right()` is the mapped object. What is the best way to handle this use case? Some sample code below:

```
val list: Collection<Object> // some collection
val eithers: List<Either<ConvertError, NewObject>> = list.map { convert(it) } // through some logic, convert each object in the collection 

val desired: Either<ConvertError, Collection<NewObject>> = eithers.map { ??? } 


fun convert(o: Object) : Either<ConvertError, NewObject> { ... }
```

Essentially, I'd like to call a mapping function on a collection of data, and if any of the mappings respond with a failure, I'd like to have an `Either.Left()` containing the error. And then otherwise, I'd like the `Either.Right()` to contain all of the mapped objects.

Any ideas for a clean way to do this? Ideally, I'd like to make a chain of function calls, but have the ability to percolate an error up through the function calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Arrow's computation blocks to unwrap `Either` inside `map` like so:

```kotlin
import arrow.core.Either
import arrow.core.computations.either

val list: ListObject> // some collection
val eithers: List<Either<ConvertError, NewObject>> = list.map { convert(it) } // through some logic, convert each object in the collection 

val desired: Either<ConvertError, Collection<NewObject>> = either.eager {
  eithers.map { convert(it).bind() } 
}

fun convert(o: Object) : Either<ConvertError, NewObject> { ... }
```

Here `bind()` will either unwrap `Either` into `NewObject` in the case `Either` is `Right`, or it will exit the `either.eager` block in case it finds `Left` with `ConvertError`. Here we're using the `eager { }` variant since we're assigning it to a `val` immediately. The main `suspend fun either { }` block supports `suspend` functions inside but is itself also a `suspend` function.

This is an alternative to the `traverse` operator.
The `traverse` operation will be simplified in Arrow 0.12.0 to the following:

```kotlin
import arrow.core.traverseEither

eithers.traverseEither(::convert)
```

The `traverse` operator is also available in Arrow Fx Coroutines with support for traversing in parallel, and some powerful derivatives of this operation.

```kotlin
import arrow.fx.coroutines.parTraverseEither

eithers.parTraverseEither(Dispatcheres.IO, ::convert)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a frequent one, what you're looking for is called `traverse`. It's like `map`, except it collects the results following the aggregation rules of the content.

So, `list.k().traverse(Either.applicative()) { convert(it) }` will return `Either.Left` is any of the operations return `Left`, and `Right<List<` otherwise.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what `.k()` does, can you explain what that's doing and why it's needed? I appreciate the concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about `arrow.core.IterableKt#sequenceEither`?

```kotlin
val desired: Either<ConvertError, Collection<NewObject>> = eithers.sequenceEither()
```